# A choice question on determinants

Tags: determinant

> If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of order $2$, then $\det(A+B)=0$ is possible only when:
>   
> $(a)$ $\det(A)=0$ or $\det(B)=0$
> $(b)$ $\det(A)+\det(B)=0$ 
>  $(c)$ $\det(A)=0$ and $\det(B)=0$
>  $(d)$ $A+B=0$

I was sure that when $A+B=0$, $\det(A+B)=\det(0)=0$ So the answer is $d$.
But I am not able to show that the other three does not meet the condition. 
Please offer your assistance?

Thank you  :)

Comment: This question is broken! Did you translate it into English yourself, perhaps? It's not true that $\det(A+B) = 0$ is possible only when $A+B = 0$. For instance, if $A = 0$ and $B$ is any non-zero matrix with zero determinant, then $\det(A+B) = 0$ but $A+B \ne 0$. (And please don't ask, "Can you prove it?")

Comment: I didnt translate it. It is posted as it is. I agree that "It's not true that $det(A+B)=0$ is possible only when $A+B=0$." But what it means in this context is that **$det(A+B)$ is true when only one among the four options(conditions) is true**. :)

Comment: and Ill change that prove that.

Comment: So instead of "is possible only when", you mean "is always true when". Right? They're not the same!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexamples,

case (a),(b),(c) take $A=I,B=-I$

Then $(A+B)=0\Rightarrow \det(A+B)=0$ but $\det(A)=\det(B)=1$

Comment: I get that. But u cant prove it?

Comment: @chndn, providing a counterexample in this case IS proof. Providing a counterexample shows that the relationship is not always true, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: okay thankyou ...  +1 to all

Comment: Counterexample implies that you have to find an exmaple in which the stated condition is not satisfied(this disproves the fact) so there is nothing like proving.

Answer (score 5):

All the answers aren't true: counterexample
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix},
B =  \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Can you prove it ?

Comment: To prove that the answers aren't true it suffice to give a counterexample

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the counter-example for (a), (b), and (c):

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 
\end{bmatrix},
B =  \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Can you prove it ?